# how to call functions of child component from appcomponent dynamically in angular5?

Tags: angular, angular5

I have a save button on navigation bar which is in app.component.html and when I click on save, form of the current page should get saved.

Problem is that I was not able to link the save icon in App component to `save()` method in child components. Can someone please help me on this?

I already tried using `@ViewChild` but I need `save()` call to happen dynamically as there are many child components.

Comment: Can you paste some code that you've actually writtern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of approaches that you can use.

The most *different* would be to use a redux based approach in your app using [Ngrx](https://github.com/ngrx/platform). I highly recommend this approach as it will lead to a cleaner application.

Alternatively, you can use a service that houses the `submit` code that is can be injected into any child component. An example Plunkr can be found here https://plnkr.co/edit/IOMT14ObtUk0jLSutlHK?p=preview